# typescript return array of key based on given value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, ecmascript-6

I want to return array of keys in an object based on a given value

Comment: Please add example input/output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way of doing it with `Object.keys()`:

```
const keys = Object.keys(obj2).filter(k => obj2[k] == "02");
```

This will make `keys` an array of keys in `obj2` whose property is `"02"`.

Answer (score 2):

You get keys of object using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and then [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the keys which have value equal to given value.

```js
const obj2 = {a: '01', b: '02', bb: '02', bbb: '02'};

function findKeys(obj,value){
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key] === value);
}
console.log(findKeys(obj2,'02'));  //["b","bb","bbb"]
console.log(findKeys(obj2,'01'));  //["a"]
```